# Access image with PHP when the file name is unknown

Tags: php, image

How could I get `image` using `PHP` if I don't know it's name?

Explanation: when user uploads image to the server, the image gets such name: `user_id_timestamp.jpg`. Now I want to access this image, but I only know half of it's name: `<img src="user_id_*.jpg"/>`. The `*` part is `unknown`. Thanks for help.

Comment: Why not save the timestamp too?

Comment: If you know the directory to which the image is written, you may be able to use PHP's [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to find it.

Comment: So, which one do you want to select if the user has several images? The latest timestamp? Is it Unix timestamp or another format?

Comment: What did you try? Did you check $_FILES ? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your looking for `glob()`

So you can do something like this:

```
<?php

    $userId = 234567865;

    foreach (glob($userId . "_*.jpg") as $filename)
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br />";

?>
```

Example output could be:

```
234567865_1418760613.jpg size 879394
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to stop the script if you found the image you can use this:

```
<?php

    $userId = 234567865;
    $pattern = $userId . "_*.jpg";

    foreach (glob($pattern) as $filename) {

        if (strpos($filename, $userId) !== true) {
            echo "User: $userId File: $filename";
            break;
        }

    }

?>
```

Example output could be:

```
User: 234567865 File: 234567865_1418760151.jpg
```

If you have multiple files from the same user and you want the image with the newest timestamp use this:

```
<?php

    $userId = 234567865;
    $pattern = $userId . "_*.jpg";

    $last = 0;
    $newest = 0;

    foreach (glob($pattern) as $filename) {

        if(substr($filename, strpos($filename, "_") + 1) > $last)
            $newest = $filename;

        $last = substr($filename, strpos($filename, "_") + 1);
    }

    echo "The newest avatar image from user: $userId is: $newest";

?>
```

Example output could be:

```
The newest avatar image from user: 234567865 is: 234567865_1418760151.jpg
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: That will work if a user has only one image. If the user has many, `glob()` will return them all. I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @HoboSapiens It's the only way he can search for this pattern, otherwise he can't get the image if he don't know the name! Also he never know's if it's the right one, because he don't know the name to compare it! So with this way he has at least all possible images and he know's that it's one of thous images since it matches the pattern.

Comment: Do you know the directory where the image is saved? And do you want to grab the image with the newest timestamp if a user has multiple?

Comment: I'm using GLOB now: `$file=glob('user_id_*.jpg'); echo $file[0];` The problem with GLOB is that it goes through all files and looks for all matches. There will be only one image per user (in a directory with a lot of other images by other users), so maybe there is more efficient way?

Comment: Do you know the user id from the user?

Comment: @user1745558 If you're only storing one image per user store it with the user ID and drop the timestamp.

Comment: I do know all the information, except for timestamp in the image name. I add timestamp, so the browser can redownload cached image (user's avatar) if user has changed it.

Comment: @user1745558 So you know the `user id` and you keep the `timestamp` if the user change his avatar? IF yes you can just change `user_id` in `glob` and use variable with the user id!

Comment: I cannot drop the timeatamp. The image is user's avatar. There are lots of users and lots of avatars. The user can change his avatar whenever he wants and I need the browser to redownload it when image changes.

Comment: @user1745558 updated my answer how it could look like

Comment: I will explain better: somebody logs in to the site, finds some other user and clicks on it. Then server gets information about that user using his user_id. His avatar is a part of informatiom. Server does not know full path to image. With glob I can scan all the files and get the one I need, but can I find that one file and stop looking? More like `<img src="user_id_*.jpg"/>` and not like `$img=glob('user_id_*.jpg');echo '<img src="'.$img[0].'"/>` (I just want to save resources).

Comment: @user1745558 updated my answer again! I think you look for my second script! After you found the file it breaks the loop and stops!

Comment: When glob() is called, it scans all the files and saves matches into array. The provided script will only print one item in array, but the server resources will still be wasted. There will always be only one file to find, so glob() might not be the best solution. Thank you for help, but don't worry, I'll figure something out.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the edit. If I use foreach and break after the image is found, it should stop glob() from going on.

Comment: @user1745558 yes since it search for the pattern, if it matches it goes through the loop and then you can break it